# Python WebScraping Script inside SSIS Package during ETL

Tags: python, ssis, web-scraping

Can we run a Python Web-Scraping Code inside SSIS. If Yes, What is the effect of Using Beautiful Soup & Selenium ? Which one can be preferred. Is there a better way to run this.

My Requirement is to, get the data from the website using python script and store it in a table every time I run the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run python script from within SSIS by calling the .py script file from execute process task. That being said, the server where this is being run needs to have the Python installed.

Comment: because the script is going to Interact with the web browser, wouldn't it affect the Process? Say in my script when I run it on pycharm I call Google Chrome to do this Job.

Comment: What happens with the process outside is unrelated to SSIS. At the end of it, SSIS Execute Process task would be looking for an exit code of either 0 or 1 (Success or Failure) and based on that, it will control how the package flows.

Comment: Thanks Sir ! I will run the package later on and get back to you. My only Concern is it opens the Web browser and redirects the pages everytime to webscrape the data. Still, I may be wrong. I will work on it later tonight and update here. Thanks again.