# SSIS Script Transformation Editor -type or namespace name 'WebScrape' could not be found are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, namespaces

I'm using VS 2019 with SQL Server 2017.  I have a SSIS Package and a Script Transformation Editor that is executing some c# code.

This is the main.cs:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WebScrape;


#endregion

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    
       

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        /*
         * Add your code here
         */
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        /*
         * Add your code here
         */
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        try
        {
            WebScrape WBScrape = new WebScrape();
            Row.DescriptionText = WBScrape.read_text_page(Row.Links);
        }
        catch (Exception UnknownError1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(UnknownError1.Message);

        }
    }

}
```

This is the WebScrape.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SC_68c409392de64cb2b3012e25a1dc514c
{
    class WebScrape
    {
        const string HTML_TAG_PATTERN = @"(<(!--|script) (.|\n[^<]) * (--|script)>)|(<|&lt;) (/?[\w!?]+)\s?[^<]*(>|&gt;)|(\&[\w]+\;)";

        private string StripHTML(string inputString)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(inputString, HTML_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty);
        }

        public string read_text_page (string pagelink)
        {
            string tempstring = string.Empty;
            int count = 0;
            string hold_temp_values = string.Empty;

            // used to build entire input
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //used on each read operation
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

            //prepare the web page we will be asking for
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pagelink);

            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36";

            // execute the request
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            // we will read data via the response stream
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            do
            {
                // fill the buffer with data
                count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                // make sure we read some data
                if (count != 0)
                {
                    //transalate from bytes to ASCII text
                    tempstring = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

                    // continue building the string
                    sb.Append(tempString);

                }

            }
            while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

            hold_temp_values = StripHTML(sb.ToString()).Trim();

            if (hold_temp_values.Length > 8000)
            {
                hold_temp_values = hold_temp_values.Substring(0, 8000);

            }

            else
            {

            }

            return hold_temp_values;

        }
    }
}
```

When I try to build the project I keep receiving the error in the Main.cs:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       The type or namespace name 'WebScrape' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why is it complaining?  I have a WebScrape class created and I'm referencing WebScrape in the Namespace in Main.  I have also tried referencing the fully qualified namespace in Main.cs to no avail:

```
using WebScrape.SC_68c409392de64cb2b3012e25a1dc514c;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is webscrape running on the client and is library on the server?

Comment: its just a local install of Visual Studio on my laptop

Comment: You have a connection which has both a client and server even if you have one machine with a virtual connection.  Do you have one or two applications?  It is possible for both the client and server to be in one application, but the IP address is normally in the socket and not passed through the application classes.

Comment: mmmmm how do I get around it?

Comment: You are defining the wescrape in the client section of the code.  Do you need same in server code?  Where is the server code?

Comment: its just a script transformation task within Microsoft SQL Server SSIS

Comment: Than the machine where the SSIS is running need to be able to located the dll.  SSIS is not part of your c# code, it is a different application (a server) that your web application is connecting to.  Maybe call a python script : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787228/python-webscraping-script-inside-ssis-package-during-etl?force_isolation=true